# Qt creator platform codegen flags

Tags: c++, linux, g++, qt-creator, opensuse

Seems Qt creator "platform codegen flags" does not take effect (Tools->Options...->Build&Run->Compillers). Mentioned there "-std=c++11" flag however it was not added to Makefile. Also added g++-5 there - also no effect:
CXX           = g++
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -Wall -W $(DEFINES)

Should be:
CXX           = g++-5
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -Wall -W $(DEFINES) -std=c++11

How to correctly add flags there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `qmake` as build system, then you can add flags to the compiler via `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` variable in your `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

And specify a compiler for C++:

```
QMAKE_CXX = g++-5
```

Also you can pass additional arguments to `make` in the "Projects" tab.

Don't know what is "platform codegen flags" though.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich I've found it but I don't know what they do.

Comment: Thanks much @OlegAndriyanov for QMAKE_CXXFLAGS, forgot about this, works now!

Comment: The qmake variable option isn't the best solution.  Particularly, for example, if building multiple architectures from the same .pro file, it is painful to add conditional variable declarations when the flags properly belong to the compiler spec (- though I also can't get Platform codegen flags to have any effect)